# ASP.Net Custom Paging (w/ C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Cenario:
I have a GridView bound to a DataSource, every column is sortable.
my main query is something like:

```
select a, b, c, d, e, f from table order by somedate desc
```

i added a filter form where i can define values to each one of the fields and get the results of a where form. As a result from this, i had to do a custom sorting so that when i sort by a field, i am sorting the filtered query and not the main one.
Now i have to do custom paging, for the same reason, but i don't understand the philosophy of it: I want to guarantee that i can:

1. filter the results
2. sort by a column
3. when i click on page 2, i get page two of the filtered and sorted results

I don't know what i have to do, so i can bind the GV with this. My sorting Method, that is working just fine looks something like:

```
string condition = GetConditions(); //gets  a string like " where a>1 and b>2" depending on the filter the user defines
string query = "select a, b, c, d, e, f from table ";
string direction = (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)? "asc": "desc";
string order = " order by " + e.SortExpression + " " + direction;
UtilizadoresDataSource.SelectCommand = query + condition + order;
```

i've never done custom paging, i am trying:
   GetConditions() //no problem here
   How can i find out how the GridView is sorted (by what field and sortingorder)?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can use ROW_NUMBER to get the number of rows that a query is returning and then filter only those element that will be visible for the given page. For example you should add ROW_NUMBER function in the select clause and add the filtering in the where cause.

```
string condition = GetConditions(); //gets  a string like " where a>1 and b>2" depending on the filter the user defines
string query = "select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY " + order + ") a, b, c, d, e, f from table ";
string direction = (e.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)? "asc": "desc";
string order = " order by " + e.SortExpression + " " + direction;
condition = condition + " RowNo  BETWEEN ((@Page - 1) * @PageSize + 1) AND (@Page * @PageSize) "
UtilizadoresDataSource.SelectCommand = query + condition + order;
```

You can find a more detailed example [here](http://www.asp101.com/articles/gal/effectivepaging/default.asp).It also contains a sample project with binding a grid.

P.S. I would suggest you to create a stored procedure and pass the parameters from the code behind. This can increase the speed and also it easier to maintain.

Comment: ok, i had thought about that, but that contradicts my preconceived notion of how .Net treated data when paging in a GridView. I thought the query was made to SQL without page restrictions and was stored in the ASP side, and when you were paging it just browsed through the data stored instead of querying the database again.
Well, thanx anyway :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but after crashing and burning, i found that this can't possibly be the only way. i'll explain later, when have the time

Comment: so, as promised, i am going to tell you why this can't be the only answer.
If I bind the gridview to a datasource whose select command uses Row_Number(), when paging, i get the real rownumbers, ie, in page two, i get rownumber 11, through 20. This means that i was right assuming that .Net stores the whole data and, when it pages, it doesn't query the SQL table everytime as it uses that stored data.